# CDATA in XML Arrays extraction

Tags: php, json, xml

Hi i have a section of an XML out put that contains

```
<Question type="2" text="Which one of the following area codes is associated with you?">
<Answer correct="false">606</Answer>
<Answer correct="false">859</Answer>
<Answer correct="false">616</Answer>
<Answer correct="false">614/380</Answer>
<Answer correct="false">812</Answer>
<Answer correct="true">502</Answer>
<Answer correct="false">810</Answer>
<Answer correct="false">740</Answer>
<Answer correct="false">248</Answer>
<Answer correct="false">None of the above</Answer>
</Question>
```

I am using this to parse the Response

```
$objXmlDocument = simplexml_load_string($response,null,LIBXML_NOCDATA);
 
if ($objXmlDocument === FALSE) {
    echo "There were errors parsing the XML file.\n";
    foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
        echo $error->message;
    }
    exit;
}
 
$objJsonDocument = json_encode($objXmlDocument);
$arrOutput = json_decode($objJsonDocument,TRUE);
```

When the results are returned i get the type of question but i do not get the correct value field. Is it because of the depth in the structure ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, seems like just the first (envelope) gets its attributes *in the array*.

You would need to loop through them.

Example:

```
$response = '<Question type="2" text="Which one of the following area codes is associated with you?">
    <Answer correct="false">606</Answer>
    <Answer correct="false">859</Answer>
    <Answer correct="false">616</Answer>
    <Answer correct="false">614/380</Answer>
    <Answer correct="false">812</Answer>
    <Answer correct="true">502</Answer>
    <Answer correct="false">810</Answer>
    <Answer correct="false">740</Answer>
    <Answer correct="false">248</Answer>
    <Answer correct="false">None of the above</Answer>
    </Question>';

$objXmlDocument = simplexml_load_string($response, null, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
if ($objXmlDocument === false) {
    echo "There were errors parsing the XML file.\n";
    foreach (libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
        echo $error->message;
    }
    exit;
}

$arrOutput = json_decode(json_encode($objXmlDocument), true);
unset($arrOutput['Answer']);
foreach ($objXmlDocument as $key => $answer) {
    $arrOutput[$key][] = json_decode(json_encode($answer), true);
}

echo var_export($arrOutput, true) . PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
[
    '@attributes' => [
        'type' => '2',
        'text' => 'Which one of the following area codes is associated with you?',
    ],
    'Answer'      => [
        0 => [
            '@attributes' => [
                'correct' => 'false',
            ],
            0             => '606',
        ],
        1 => [
            '@attributes' => [
                'correct' => 'false',
            ],
            0             => '859',
        ],
        2 => [
            '@attributes' => [
                'correct' => 'false',
            ],
            0             => '616',
        ],
        3 => [
            '@attributes' => [
                'correct' => 'false',
            ],
            0             => '614/380',
        ],
        4 => [
            '@attributes' => [
                'correct' => 'false',
            ],
            0             => '812',
        ],
        5 => [
            '@attributes' => [
                'correct' => 'true',
            ],
            0             => '502',
        ],
        6 => [
            '@attributes' => [
                'correct' => 'false',
            ],
            0             => '810',
        ],
        7 => [
            '@attributes' => [
                'correct' => 'false',
            ],
            0             => '740',
        ],
        8 => [
            '@attributes' => [
                'correct' => 'false',
            ],
            0             => '248',
        ],
        9 => [
            '@attributes' => [
                'correct' => 'false',
            ],
            0             => 'None of the above',
        ],
    ],
];
```

You now just need to sort out what you want from that data.

EDIT: this is not "elegant". Perhaps you just should use the attribute get method ect to build an array of what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, avoid the json_decode route. Too much work. Here is an elegant way - clean neat code that one would easily understand.

```
<?php
    $xmlstring = '<Question type="2" text="Which one of the following area codes is associated with you?">
<Answer correct="false">606</Answer>
<Answer correct="false">859</Answer>
<Answer correct="false">616</Answer>
<Answer correct="false">614/380</Answer>
<Answer correct="false">812</Answer>
<Answer correct="true">502</Answer>
<Answer correct="false">810</Answer>
<Answer correct="false">740</Answer>
<Answer correct="false">248</Answer>
<Answer correct="false">None of the above</Answer>
</Question>';

$initialize = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstring);

//extract the attributes text and type below
$accessQuestionText = $initialize->attributes()->text;
$accessQuestionType = $initialize->attributes()->type;

//using for each loop lets iterate over the Possible Answers
foreach($initialize->Answer as $answers){

    echo "Question of Type $accessQuestionType is $accessQuestionText ";
    echo "The List of Dropdown answers can be ".$answers."<br>";
}
```

Output Looks like this:

[image]